# Understanding OutputStream

Tags: java

I am trying to understand outputStream first.I am reading from the book Java network programming 2ns edition by Merlin Hughes . There is a sample program in the book which i am trying to run and get its output but there is no output.i understand it but could not identify the problem .

here is the code

```
import java.io.*;

public class SimpleOut 
{
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
  {
    for (int i=0; i<args.length; i++)
    {
        println (args[i]);
    }
  }

  public static void println(String msg) throws IOException
  {
    synchronized (System.out)
    {
        for (int i=0 ; i<msg.length(); i++)
            System.out.write(msg.charAt (i) & 0xff);

        System.out.write('\n');
    }
    System.out.flush();
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you passing [command-line arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html) to the program?

Comment: what do you want to understand? sysout!!!<!-------->

Comment: Got it ,Thanks .Didnt know about command line arguments (Y)

Comment: I understood the code.i didnt know about CLA ,i am noob if thats what you wanna hear NFE :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like you are not passing any **[command-line arguments](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/cmdLineArgs.html)** while running the program.

> When an application is launched, the runtime system passes the command-line arguments to the application's main method via an array of Strings.

**Example:** User should enter

```
java NameOfFile arg1 arg2 arg3
```

Comment: Could you tell me what happens when synchronized (System.out) is executed.synchronized is used for synchronizing a thread ,how System.out is a thread?

Comment: Not an expert in that field. Try **to do some research** and if you can't figure it out, post it in StackOverflow as a different question. Feel free to accept this answer if it was useful and solved your problem: [How does accepting an answer work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: i am not allowed to ask more questions for 24 hours :(

Comment: Try to do some research an [read this.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/182380/237562)